# How to control input feature size/dimension in chainer?

Tags: chainer

For example, the FC layer(L.Linear) needs input_size and output_size , but this is only set for weight matrix in FC. But the input image size can be arbitrary, how to control to limit the input image size or input other feature size?

Answer (score 1):

I've made a new pooling function for considering specific output shape in Chainer :

```
# pooling_func : F.max_pooling_2d or F.average_pooling_2d
def output_shape_pooling(self, x,output_size , pooling_func):
       input_size  = x.shape[-1]
       stride = input_size // output_size
       k_size = input_size - (output_size -1 ) * stride
       x      = pooling_func(x , stride=stride,ksize=k_size)
       return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Linear link can be defined as two way

1. Explicitly specify input_size

   ```
   l1 = L.Linear(input_size, output_size)
   ```
2. Infer input size

   ```
   l1 = L.Linear(None, output_size)
   # Following code works same way, from chainer v2
   # l1 = L.Linear(output_size)
   ```

When the second method is used, **input size is determined (and weight matrix is created) automatically at the first time of forward computation,** and this input size is fixed following forward computation.

In your case, do you use FC layer after the convolution layer (which is the common structure for image classification network in CNN)?
In this case, I guess the image size should always be the same with the first time of forward computation (unless the image size is ignored by global pooling etc).
Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: My question is more complicated than this, I mean, when I custom myself define Link, How to limit the input feature size, Or it is no need to do this? only to set my weight matrix is enough just like L.Linear? How to limit user input feature( e.g. word dimension, image dimension?)

Comment: Why you need to limit it?

Comment: because my weight shape depends on the input feature, just like L.Linear

Comment: Then can you refer the Linear link implementation code, https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/v3.0.0rc1/chainer/links/connection/linear.py#L98-L113, to meet your spec?